# Accessing Q &A on PowerBI desktop?

Tags: powerbi, powerbi-desktop

I know we can access Q&A on PowerBI service, but how to access it on PowerBI desktop.

(Q&A feature works on natural language processing, you can ask powerBI, whats the sales for this month and so on)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Q&A is available on the desktop, of you double click on the desktop it should pop up with a Q&A box. Or use the Q&A visual. It will allow you to ask a question, and create the chart. A good outline is on the Microsoft docs site below:

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/power-bi/visuals/power-bi-visualization-q-and-a